# Apple verifyReceipt works in sandbox but not in production

Tags: c#, ios, in-app-purchase

We have code that runs for a couple of years as expected and a couple of days ago it started acting weird.

Using : https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt , our purchases works.
Using : https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt , our purchases returns code 21002.

We use this code from sandbox environment and usually the production link returned code 21007 and than we tried sandbox.
Now that it suddenly return 21002 only in production we are not sure what is the issue here.

Can someone help please?

Comment: Did you resolve your problem, and if yes how ?